# Initramfs booting failure

Tags: boot, 20.04, initramfs

After a hard reboot of my Ubuntu 20.04 system, I got [this boot issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vmXt.jpg).

What I've tried fruitlessly so far:

1. Repair the boot with `boot-repair` from a Live CD.
2. Rebuild my ramdisk with `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`.

The both solutions seem to be typical troubleshooting methods in case of initramfs booting issues, but they didn't work for me. Could anybody suggest something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check and repair your file system...

At the boot error message...

Hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to enter maintenance mode.

If you reach an initramfs prompt, type:

```
fsck -f /dev/sda2
```

If you reach a # prompt, type:

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2
```

Then type:

```
reboot
```

**Update #1:**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thanks, but all what I get from it is a notification that '/dev/sda2 is mounted' and 'e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.' Of course, nothing changes after rebooting.
I tried both commands with and without 'sudo'.

Comment: @tarasiy See Update #1 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to maintenance mode by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then type

```sh
journalctl -xb | grep "RUN fsck MANUALLY"
```

You'll will probably see a message like this

```
Oct 02 20:55:59 NAME systemd-fsck (839) : /dev/sdaX: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
```

where X in `/dev/sdaX` is a number. Then enter this command.

```sh
fsck -y /dev/sdaX
```

replace X with whatever number you saw earlier on your screen. That should probably fix it.

If you see an error like, `/dev/sdaX is mounted` then reboot and open root shell from Advanced boot options. Unmount the filesystem using `sudo umount /dev/sdaX` and again try,

```sh
fsck -y /dev/sdaX
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)